# ZAP API, what do you need to enter to set up the authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, parameters, zap

Im automating ZAP using it's Java API. I have several situations, where I need to set up the authentication. To do that, there is following method:

```
public ApiResponse setAuthenticationMethod(
       String contextid, String authmethodname, String authmethodconfigparams){
       ...
}
```

I haven't found anything on the ZAP homepage, to what specific things you need to enter in authmethodname and authmethodconfigparams. In what form do these need to be entered? For example for the authentication I need form-based. Is the string for that "form", "form-based" etc., or what do I need to enter?

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend that you configure *and test* authentication using the ZAP desktop, then export your context and any other settings so that you can them import them via the API. Its much easier to do that and much easier to test as well.
Authentication is hard, not just in ZAP. For more details see these workshop videos which focus on authentication and automation: https://www.zaproxy.org/addo-auth-workshop/

Comment: I have a lot of contexts to make and they will change over time. So my idea was, that I can give them in with a java config.properties file. Then I can make new contexts as I need them in a much easier way. But for that I would have to give those parameters in the methods, isn't that possible? I would just need to know how to enter the `authmethodconfigparams`for the authentication and the `authcredentialsconfigparams` for the users.

Comment: In that case get it working via the desktop then work out what properties you need to set. Those videos cover quite a few variations...

Comment: I found this [example](https://github.com/pdsoftplan/zap-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/clientapi/examples/AuthenticationApiExample.java) and followed it, but I still get the errormessage, that there is a parameter missing. I am sorry to bother you but I just can't fix it. The only difference to the example code ist, that in the `setAuthenticationCredentials`Method I don't give the apikey because the method doesn't need it, when I look at the source code. But at least the AuthenticationMethod setup works now